# error: Environment variable not found: DATABASE_URL while using prisma

Tags: node.js, prisma

My prisma isn't able to find .env file even though that file is create by `npx prisma init`.

Folder Structure:

```
--prisma
  -- schema.prisma
--.env
--script.ts
```

Schema code:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id   Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  name String
}
```

.env:

`DATABASE_URL="postgres://xxxxxx:xxxx@ep-jolly-dew-42750400.ap-southeast-1.aws.neon.tech/test"`

script.ts:

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client/edge'
const prisma = new PrismaClient()


const main = async () => {
    const user = await prisma.user.create({data:{name:"Sai"}})
    console.log(user)
} 

main()
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    .finally(async () => {
        await prisma.$disconnect()
    })
```

Error prisma show while running the script.ts file:

```
PrismaClientInitializationError: 
Invalid `prisma.user.create()` invocation:


error: Environment variable not found: DATABASE_URL.
```

I tried running,
`npx prisma migrate -dev --name init` and also `npx prisma generate`

Still showing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the exact same issue on my Ubuntu20 server, So I directly added the env variable to server environment. with given command.

```
export DATABASE_URL=postgresql://test:test@localhost:5432/test
```

This really fixed my issue.

You can check the [reference](https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/more/development-environment/environment-variables/managing-env-files-and-setting-variables#manually-set-an-environment-variable-on-a-maclinux-system)

Answer (score 0):

instead of using **@prisma/client/edge** use **@prisma/client** 
`import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'`